# How to add more data to datatables.net table when you don't know the number of final rows you'll get and you can only pull 100 rows at a time?

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I'm using DataTables.net and what I'm doing is pulling the first 100 rows. Each group is only 100. The PHP call is for page 1 at first.

Here's the link to my site what I'm trying to do in a rudimentary fashion, not yet incorporated in my full site:

http://magicdjs.com/getinventoryitemsaddedbetween1.html

Now, what I need to do, to gather all the rows, is keep pulling until 100 is NOT the number of rows. This means, I've reached the end.  I'm told there are 70 pages of 100 rows each with the last one being less than 100.

Here's my JS call:

```
/* global currentTable */

let theRows;
let theTable;
let theAjax;
let theColumns;
let pageNbr = 1;
let newPageNbr = 0;

let dt;
let detailRows = [];
let myTable, myAjax, myRows, myCols;
let myJSON;
let table;
let headers;
let $ = jQuery.noConflict();
let data = [];
let fixedData = [];

'use strict';

headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http, data',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    //'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
};
// DT Debugger. Uncomment to use
// (function() {
//     var url = 'https://debug.datatables.net/bookmarklet/DT_Debug.js';
//     if (typeof DT_Debug != 'undefined') {
//         if (DT_Debug.instance !== null) {
//             DT_Debug.close();
//         } else {
//             new DT_Debug();
//         }
//     } else {
//         var n = document.createElement('script');
//         n.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript');
//         n.setAttribute('src', url + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime());
//         document.body.appendChild(n);
//     }
// })();

theTable = "magicdatatable";

$(document).ready(async() => {

    if (sessionStorage.getItem("magic") === null) {

        callMurphs = () => {

            let url = "services.php";
            let user_id = "djpeterb@magicdjs.com";


            try {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { user_id: user_id, page: pageNbr },
                    success: (thedata) => {
                        console.log("data returned: ", thedata);
                        if (thedata.status == 200) {
                            console.log(thedata.statusText + "data returned: ", thedata);
                            data = [];
                            data.push(thedata);
                            console.log("New Data: ", data);
                            data.map(el => {
                                delete el["status"],
                                    delete el["statusText"]
                            });
                            sessionStorage.setItem("magic1", JSON.stringify(data[0]));
                            data = [];
                            data.push(sessionStorage.getItem("magic0"));
                            callTable(1);
                        } else {
                            console.log("no data returned inside success: ", thedata.statusText);
                            sessionStorage.setItem("magic1", "No Magic Found Captain!" + thedata.statusText);
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function(data) {
                        console.log("All Done!");
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("An Error occured: ", e);
            }

        }

        callMurphs();

    } else {
        data = [];
        if (data.length === 0) {
            data.push(sessionStorage.getItem("magic1"));
        }
        table = $("#" + theTable).DataTable({

            "data": JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("magic0")).data,
            "columns": [{
                    "className": 'dt-control',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": ''
                },
                {
                    "data": "id",
                    className: "producttabletxt"
                },
                {
                    "data": "title",
                    className: "producttabletxt"
                },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    className: "producttabletxt",
                    render: (data, type, row) => {
                        let retVal = "";

                        if (data.categories.string === undefined) {
                            retVal = "<strong>No Categories Listed</strong>";
                        } else {
                            retVal = data.categories.string;
                        }
                        return retVal;
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    className: "producttabletxt",
                    render: (data, type, row) => {
                        let retVal = "";

                        if (data.artist_magician === "") {
                            retVal = "<strong>No Magician Listed</strong>";
                        } else {
                            retVal = data.artist_magician;
                        }
                        return retVal;
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "qty",
                    className: "producttabletxt"
                },
                {
                    type: "currency",
                    "data": null,
                    render: (data, type, row) => {
                        return "<strong>$" + parseFloat(data.price).toFixed(2) + "</strong>";
                    },
                    className: 'dt-body-right'
                }
            ],
            "order": [
                [1, "asc"]
            ]
        });
    }

    callTable = (page) => {

            let sessionItemPage;

            if (page === null) {
                sessionItemPage = "magic0";
            } else {
                sessionItemPage = "magic" + page;
            }

            table = $("#" + theTable).DataTable({

                "data": JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(sessionItemPage)).data,
                "columns": [{
                        "className": 'dt-control',
                        "orderable": false,
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": ''
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "id",
                        className: "producttabletxt"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "title",
                        className: "producttabletxt"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": null,
                        className: "producttabletxt",
                        render: (data, type, row) => {
                            let retVal = "";

                            if (data.categories.string === undefined) {
                                retVal = "<strong>No Categories Listed</strong>";
                            } else {
                                retVal = data.categories.string;
                            }
                            return retVal;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "data": null,
                        className: "producttabletxt",
                        render: (data, type, row) => {
                            let retVal = "";

                            if (data.artist_magician === "") {
                                retVal = "<strong>No Magician Listed</strong>";
                            } else {
                                retVal = data.artist_magician;
                            }
                            return retVal;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "qty",
                        className: "producttabletxt"
                    },
                    {
                        type: "currency",
                        "data": null,
                        render: function(data, type, row) {
                            return "<strong>$" + parseFloat(data.price).toFixed(2) + "</strong>";
                        },
                        className: "dt-body-right producttabletxt"
                    }
                ],
                "order": [
                    [1, "asc"]
                ]
            });
        }
        // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $("#" + theTable).on('click', 'td.dt-control', function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
    // }
});

/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
//console.log("THIS after the FORMAT Datatable: ", clicked);
format = (d) => {

    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    let tblTemp;
    console.log("Original D: ", d);
    //Find out which table we are and pull that detail template...
    switch (theTable) {
        case "magicdatatable":

            if (d.artist_magician === "") {
                d.artist_magician = "NA";
            }

            tblTemp = '<table id="magicproductdet" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped" style="padding-left:150px;">' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<td class="producttabletxt" colspan=2><strong>Magician</strong></td>' +
                '<td class="producttabletxt" colspan=2><strong>' + d.artist_magician + '</strong></td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<td class="producttabletxt" colspan=2>' + d.htmldesc + '</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<td colspan=2>' +
                '<img class="productimg" src="https://www.murphysmagicsupplies.com/images/' + d.imgfilename + '" alt="' + d.altimages + '"></td>' +
                '</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '</table>';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return tblTemp;
};

checkAllItems = () => {

    let arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(sessionStorage);

    // for (let i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
    //     console.log("SessionStorage List of Items: ", sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.key(i)));
    // }

    console.log("SessionStorage List of Item Names: ", arrayOfKeys);
    newPageNbr = arrayOfKeys.length + 1;
    addMoreData(newPageNbr)
}

addMoreData = (pgnbr) => {

    let url = "webservices/vendor/murphs/murphs-services.php";
    let user_id = "djpeterb@magicdjs.com";

    console.log("New Page Number: " + pgnbr);

    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { user_id: user_id, page: pgnbr },
            success: (thedata) => {
                console.log("data returned: ", thedata);
                if (thedata.status == 200) {
                    console.log(thedata.statusText + "data returned: ", thedata);
                    data = [];
                    data.push(thedata);
                    console.log("New Data: ", data);
                    data.map(el => {
                        delete el["status"],
                            delete el["statusText"]
                    });
                    this.addEntry(data);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("magic" + pgnbr, JSON.stringify(data[0]));
                    data = [];
                    data.push(sessionStorage.getItem("magic" + pgnbr));
                    // callTable(pgnbr);
                } else {
                    console.log("no data returned inside success: ", thedata.statusText);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("magic" + pgnbr, "No Magic Found Captain!" + thedata.statusText);
                }
            },
            complete: function(data) {
                console.log("All Done!");
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("An Error occured: ", e);
    }

}

addEntry = (newEntry) => {

    let newSortedData = {
        data: []
    };

    // Parse any JSON previously stored in allEntries
    let existingEntries = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("magic0")).data;
    if (existingEntries === null) {
        existingEntries;
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem("magic1", JSON.stringify(newEntry));
    // Save allEntries back to local storage
    let newEntries = existingEntries.concat(newEntry[0].data)

    console.log("existing entries with push for new ones: ", newEntries);

    table.clear().draw();
    newSortedData.data.push(newEntries);
    table.rows.add(_.sortBy(newSortedData, "title")); // Add new data
    table.columns.adjust().draw(); // Redraw the DataTable

    console.log("Existing and new ones sorted: ", newSortedData);

    sessionStorage.setItem("magic1", JSON.stringify(newSortedData));


};
```

What I'm trying to do is when I click "ADD MORE ROWS" button, I want to pull the next set, based on how many I have, then, concatenate the subsequent sets into the main magic0. So, essentially, I can have 70 JSON objects like you'll see when you open the DEV console.

When I push ADD MORE ROWS, I add to the counter, 1, and send that NEW number as a page number into the PHP to call the very next set of rows until I hit rows that are less than 100, meaning, I've reached the final set.

What's happening, is that I keep overwriting the original magic0 with magic(n).  I want to concatenate not replace.

Anyway, the reason for the two callTable calls is that the one buried in the callMurphs() callTable(1); can FIND the callTable function but, cannot when I'm here in the ELSE

```
} else {
        data = [];
        if (data.length === 0) {
            data.push(sessionStorage.getItem("magic1"));
        }
        table = $("#" + theTable).DataTable({
...
```

The reason I have to DUPLICATE the entire callTable function again which is nonsense.

It keeps saying, callTable is not a function otherwise.

So, yes, there are a few things but instead of making 70 PHP scripts with 100 rows each, I built one call to the PHP using an incremental system calling it ONLY when I want more rows. BUT, therein lies my problem. I'd like all 7000 rows but in a lazy loading manner which I know DataTables can do "IF" you don't have to make 70 and only 1 call with 7000+ rows.  See my issue?

Thank you.

If you need more info, please ask. The PHP is proprietary from Murphy's Magic therefore I cannot show you the KEY phrase.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the call in the PHP which will help understand why I must poll the server 70+ times.

```
$parameters = array('startDate' => $day1, 'endDate' => $day2, 'page' => $pagenbr);
try {
    $starttime = date("1900/01/01") . "T00:00:00";
    $endtime = $newDate . "T23:59:59";

    $day1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($starttime));
    $day2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endtime));

    $icount = 70;
    $ctr = 0;

    for ($i = 1; $i < $icount; $i++) {
        $ctr = $ctr + 1;
    }
    $data = $client->GetInventoryStuff($parameters);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    printf("Soap Fault: %s\n", $e->Reason);
}
```

**OF NOTE: getInventoryStuff is NOT the real name of the API as it's proprietary.**

Comment: I recommend using the Scroller plug-in, https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/, to automatically load pages of data as you scroll through the list, instead of your Add More Data button.  It's a little tricky to get working correctly, but works well once it's working.

Comment: Alan, thank you but will this work with me having to poll the server 70+ times until I hit LESS than 100 rows to tell me I'm on the final set? Remember, this is not 7000+ rows in one chunk, it's 70 calls, to the DB. Follow me?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to retrieve rows that you are not viewing. The Scroller plug-in automatically retrieves buffers of records so that where ever you scroll, the appropriate rows will be visible. You won't have to poll when using the Scroller the plug-in.  You would have to update your db query (via LIMIT) to use the paging info from Datatables.

Comment: Alan, here's the call from the PHP... and you'll see why... see EDIT... that pagenbr is what I send in to the PHP call from the JS.  I must poll the server 70+ times. It's a backwards way but that's how the API call is. Now, I have pulled in the DB into my MS SQL Server as one whole 7000+ row chunk but I'd have to constantly update my tables manually when they update theirs.  A pain.

Comment: Follow-up question: if there are say 217 rows, if you load 1st time it gets the 100 rows, and if you "load more" you will the next 100 rows (total 200 rows) , what about the last 17 rows ?? (no need to load ??)

Comment: No, I do need to load the remaining. You see, they just can't do a simple SQL with gathering all the data in one fell swoop with a group by adding a rowCount(*) as totalRows for example, No, I have to poll the server continually until I hit rows less than 100 which tells me, I've hit the last group

Comment: That's pretty simple. For 1st load (page=0) , Load the data with the page number (page=0) into a DIV say id=0; make sure at the end of the data you loaded will contain another DIV (say id=1), so when you click the next "load more", call the url again to load the next 100 records and put it into the DIV with id=1 (and so on ..... until the end).

Comment: I'm storing the results in session storage to make it easier. That's not a big issue. if you run the query in the URL, open the dev console, you'll see under application/session storage. Let me try that because they'll ding us for a lengthy conversation.  Make it a possible solution vice comments ok Ken and Alan?

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest you do is initialise an empty DataTable, and then have a loop that will hit the server, requesting the next page of data, until there is no more data available, each time adding what it gets to the DataTable using the [`rows.add()` method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()).

For example:

```js
function getData (index) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'source.php',
    data: {
      page: index
    },
    success: function (json) {
      // Check we got data back, and if so, move on to the next one
      if (json.data) {
        table.rows.add(json);

        // You might want to add a small setTimeout here to limit how fast it will hit the server
        getData(index+1);
      }
    }
}

let table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

// Start the fetch cycle
getData(table, 0);
```

Comment: table.add(json) creates an error that states: table.add() is NOT a function. Allan, I've emailed you more details.

Comment: There was a missing `.row` namespace in the example code. I got the documentation link correct, but the demo code wrong... Doh.

Comment: I only get 100 rows. It doesn't go back in the function to get the rest UNLESS... I need to show the table and click, LAST PAGE and see if it'll retrieve the rest, it's not.

Comment: Oh, and I had to put a let self = this; under this:     getData = (getData, index) => {let self = this; ...} or the getData() call was UNDEFINED, thus, I had to do, self.getData() and it called it, but only once

Comment: I had a bracket in the wrong place, which won't have helped. With that code you also need to be sure your JSON return has a `data` property. You might need to change the logic based on the JSON response from the server.

Comment: Allan, I just thought of something, why not LOOP in the PHP and bring everything back THEN I can use the scroll() method. That would bring back the result set in chucks of 100... or I can bring back ALL the results in one fell swoop. Write to a JSON file and update once a week. They have a bunch of other APIs. This is only for the API to return products between 01-1900-01 - PRESENT DAY.  Yeah, I know, there's a better way, but this is all I have to work with.

Comment: Yes that is a perfectly valid way of doing it as well. Obviously your users will need to wait longer before seeing any data is the downside. If it is valid to cache the data, then that would be much better.

Comment: What I'm doing is retrieve the rows and store in SessionStorage... still working on it.